# String transforming to columns in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a string like this:

```
"page_age:15#resp_gender:4#EN01CTY:3#QMktSize:6#Page_Device_usagesm:8"
```

and in Excel want to get a result that is formatted in columns like this:

```
Resp_gender   En01cty  Page_Device_usage
     4           3           8
```

Comment: Use a text editor (even Windows Notepad should do it) to transform that into CSV format (first row contains only headings, the rest of the rows contain only the values) and there you go. Pretty easy with search and replace to strip the field names from the data rows, and change the field separator from `#` to `,` (or `;` or whatever suits you), then add the first row with the headings in the same format.

Comment: Actually, a `#` is just as fine separator so you don't need to change that at all, but if using any other than `,` you need to use the "Text to columns" function to tell Excel how to separate the fields.

Comment: Text to columns: separator `#` 》 transpose 》 text to columns: seperator `:` 》 transpose 》 done :)

Comment: @DirkReichel You might want to convert your comment into an answer ;)

Comment: If he knows the headers, he could use `MID` + `FIND` to extract the values directly from multiple strings which would suit more for an answer...

Comment: Can we do this thru excel macro instead of text editor as I have a long list of records to be transposed.

Comment: @Rahul include all specifics of your problem in your question. Just waiting for people to do your work is not right whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, if doing this to only one line the T2C (text to columns) + C&TP (copy and transposed paste) will be enough. Just doing each step 2 times like this:

T2C with `#` separator will change

```
page_age:15#resp_gender:4#EN01CTY:3#QMktSize:6#Page_Device_usagesm:8
```

to

```
     A      |       B       |     C     |      D     |          E
page_age:15 | resp_gender:4 | EN01CTY:3 | QMktSize:6 | Page_Device_usagesm:8
```

the C&TP will change it to lines

```
page_age:15
resp_gender:4
EN01CTY:3
QMktSize:6
Page_Device_usagesm:8
```

the next T2C with `:` separator will change it to an almost finished table

```
         A          |  B
page_age            | 15
resp_gender         |  4
EN01CTY             |  3
QMktSize            |  6
Page_Device_usagesm |  8
```

the last C&TP will switch it to the look we want

```
    A    |      B      |    C    |     D    |          E
page_age | resp_gender | EN01CTY | QMktSize | Page_Device_usagesm
   15    |      4      |    3    |     6    |          8
```

However, doing this for multiple lines will be a lot of work. Let's assume for now that we are only looking for specific values having this values:

```
page_age:15#resp_gender:4#EN01CTY:3#QMktSize:6#Page_Device_usagesm:8
page_age:3#resp_gender:11#EN01CTY:9#QMktSize:4#Page_Device_usagesm:1
page_age:9#resp_gender:5#EN01CTY:7#QMktSize:2#Page_Device_usagesm:12
page_age:22#resp_gender:8#EN01CTY:1#QMktSize:5#Page_Device_usagesm:2
```

(having this in cells `A2` to `A4` because we want row 1 for headers)

What do we know? In front of the values is always a `:` and after them is a `#` (except for the last item).

What do we want? Cut the text in front and after the value we desire.

Lets assume again something: we want the values from `resp_gender`, so we set `resp_gender` as header for column B (in B1).

Starting to cut everything in front of our value. This way we need to find where it starts. The `FIND` function will do exactly this. So we try it with `=FIND(B$1,$A1)` (the `$` is for making it draggable later on), and get 13. Just put this in a `RIGHT` formula with `LEN` to test it:

```
=RIGHT($A1,LEN($A1)-FIND(B$1,$A1))
```

will get us to `esp_gender:4#EN01CTY:3#QMktSize:6#Page_Device_usagesm:8`.

OK, we need to also subtract the length of the header itself, so it becomes:

```
=RIGHT($A2,LEN($A2)-FIND(B$1,$A2)-LEN($B1))
```

and we get `4#EN01CTY:3#QMktSize:6#Page_Device_usagesm:8`. Cool, there is no need to calc the `:` because it is already cut.  All we need to do now is to cut the text after the value.

To not kill the formula and keep it short for now, we leave it in B2 as it is, and do the right cutting in C2 (just for now). As we know, we can find the `#` pretty easily with a `FIND`. Merging it with a `LEFT` formula should give us what we want:

```
=LEFT(B2,FIND("#",B2))
```

gives us `4#`. OK, one character too long, so just a `-1` will do it:

```
=LEFT(B2,FIND("#",B2)-1)
```

Now we merge both formulas to each other by simply copying the formula from B2 (without the `=`) and pasting it over each B2 in the second formula. This way we get:

```
=LEFT(RIGHT($A2,LEN($A2)-FIND(B$1,$A2)-LEN($B1)),FIND("#",RIGHT($A2,LEN($A2)
 -FIND(B$1,$A2)-LEN($B1)))-1)
```

which returns `4`. Looks like it works. Checking it for all headers we get a problem if we are going for the last part (which isn't followed by a `#`).  But a simple `IFERROR` will cover that. So we end up with this:

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(RIGHT($A2,LEN($A2)-FIND(B$1,$A2)-LEN($B1)),FIND("#",RIGHT($A2,LEN($A2)
 -FIND(B$1,$A2)-LEN($B1)))-1),RIGHT($A2,LEN($A2)-FIND(B$1,$A2)-LEN($B1)))
```

That was a lot of text just to get the formula you want. But just take it as a small tutorial to get your formulas in the future (always keep in mind there are different ways to get exactly this).

Comment: @fixer1234 thx for correcting the grammar in my answer :)